Compose Multiplatform code files are getting deleted automatically as i'm working
I just started working on KMP, and whenever i am busy coding, my files, directories i have written under commonMain Module just all get deleted for no reason.
I have restarted the IDE, repaired it and still the files never came back.
It has happened twice now and it's becoming frustrating.
Got this error too:
Path [/Users/adrianikeaba/Downloads/KMMProject/composeApp/src/commonMain/resources] of module [KMMProject.composeApp.commonMain] was removed from modules [KMMProject.composeApp.main]" Also 2 more paths were deduplicated. See idea log for details

The same thing happened to me twice, have you got any solution?

Just stopped, did you solve yours?
@AvinashSharma
